# Revert to Eclipse default settings

Tags: eclipse, themes

I know there is the option in Eclipse to 'restore defaults'.

The problem is I had imported a .epf to change my editors font/colors.

I'm not a big fan of the changes and would like to go back. I've tried deleting the eclipse folder and downloading a fresh copy, but the styles persist.

I assume there is a config file somewhere that I could possibly delete.

Anyway, if you could help me out here I would appreciate it. I've looked for solutions but they all seem to point to the same answer that doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 181):

You can reset to the default color scheme in the Window>Preferences options page. This example will be for resetting a theme used for Java.

Navigate to **Windows>Preferences>Java>Editor**. Click on **Syntax Coloring**. Click "**Restore Defaults**" and "**Apply**". Then, navigate to **General>Editors**. Click on **Text Editors**. Click on "**Restore Defaults**" and "**Apply**".

I had the same issue and the above steps cleared up my problem. Also, the **Show line numbers** check box is on the last page from above.

Comment: This one did not work for me. Apparently, properties change Eclipse more than can be restored by defaults.

Comment: Installing the themes plugin cured the problem and I was back where I was 25 minutes before.

Comment: Ankit Sharma suggested this approach:

For JSP Files(.jsp) - Window->Preferences->Web->Jsp Files->Editor->Syntax Coloring on right side, click on restore default and apply;

For HTML Files (.html) - Window->Preferences->Web->HTML Files->Editor->Syntax Coloring on right side, click on restore default and apply;

For CSS Files(.css Files) - Window->Preferences->Web->CSS Files->Editor->Syntax Coloring on right side, click on restore default and apply;

For JavaScript Files(.js Files) - Window->Preferences->Java Script->Editor->Syntax Coloring on right side, click on restore default and apply.

Comment: Restoring default did not revert my property file editor settings

Comment: worked. thank you. my "parameter" was white font on white background. finally i found where to restore this.

Comment: I also had to visit General->Appearance->Colors and Fonts and press the Restore Defaults buttons to correct my Package Explorer view.

Comment: In addition you should relaunch Eclipse. After that all changes are active.

Comment: This has not worked for me.  I'm trying to get away from the Dark theme.  I've even re-downloaded Eclipse and created a new workspace.  Initially everything looks fine when I open the new workspace, but if I close and re-open it, I get the Dark theme again.  How is that possible?  If there a registry setting or some external place where Eclipse settings are stored?

Answer (score 142):

I followed the instructions of Ronan on this one and worked well.

```
rm -r $WORKSPACE_DIR/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/
```

Relaunch eclipse.

I had installed the an eclipse preference for colours.

One would think eclipse could make it simpler to remove preferences than this manual process.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just followed the answer but instead deleted only two files: `org.eclipse.ui.editors.prefs` and `org.eclipse.wst.css.ui.prefs`. Worked great! :)

Comment: It worked on Spring Tool Suite

**Spring Tool Suite 

Version: 3.7.3.RELEASE
Build Id: 201602251025
Platform: Eclipse Neon (4.6)**

Comment: @JovanPerovic's two files were not enough for me, but I deleted all the ones that changed today and that worked OK.

Comment: Even if I delete the entire `.metadata` dir, Eclipse still keep the syntax coloring. It got attached to the old styles :-/

Answer (score 22):

I encountered this problem also, I went with the second answer, however, I only removed /.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings - this way I was able to preserve my workspace settings (source code etc)

Going forward I would recommend downloading the Eclipise Color Theme Plugin from http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/ - This allows you to switch between a range of color themes easily, and easily switch back to 'Default'

Answer (score 20):

It is simple.

First, you open eclipse but with workspace different with workspace you have working.
then, you choose **File** / **Export** / --> **General** / **Preferences** --> choose to folder which you want to pick the file *.epf

Second, you open eclipse with workspace you want to work. Then choose **File** / **Import** / --> **General** / **Preferences** --> choose to folder which you had picked the file *.epf and OK

Have fun!

Answer (score 11):

"Restore Defaults" is not working.

You must remove the all file in the /.../workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/ directory.

Answer (score 8):

The settings of plugins, including the core ones, are saved in the `[workspace_dir]/.metadata/.plugins` directories (`[workspace_dir]` refers to the workspace directory you use).

So if you remove the `[workspace_dir]/.metadata`, you will reset **all** the properties defined (which will include all the properties, not only the font ones). Another idea is to create and use a new workspace. Be careful, as your code source may be located in your `[workspace_dir]/` directory.

But why don't you just use `Use System Font` button in the Eclipse Properties dialog?

Comment: I have a lot of work already in my current workspace which is why I didn't want to create another. I'll give you're advice a try

Comment: This can mess up the workspace in ways difficult to recover. Be sure to copy your .metadata directory before altering it.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. My path back to default was as follows:

1. Install **Eclipse Color Themes** Plugin (http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/)
2. Navigate to **Window->Preferences**
3. Navigate to **General->Appearance->Color Themes**
4. Click **Restore Defaults**, then click **Apply**

That should take care of it.

Answer (score 5):

To me the first answer by **Rikus Khan** was almost what I needed. It wasn't enough to go to ,e.g. **General > Editors > Text editors** and click **Restore Defaults**. I had to choose every single subcategory, namely: **Accessibility**, **Annotations**, **Hyperlinking**, etc., and manually restore their defaults as well. Apparently restoring defaults doesn't propagate down the tree.

The problem I had was the underscoring of warnings and errors in Java editor changed to highliting (after importing **RainbowDrops.epf**, recommended by the MoonRise UI Theme) and didn't want to revert when changing syntax coloring and other related options. This option itself is located in the aforementioned **Annotations > Errors** and **Warnings**.

Answer (score 4):

I went to My workspace

> directory/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/

and then deleted all recently added files !!

Answer (score 2):

Deleting everything under your workspace's `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings` will restore to defaults but you will lose every other setting too. You can selectively undo changes made by importing RainbowDrops.epf

Open `RanbowDrops.epf`. Mine looks like this

```
file_export_version=3.0
/instance/ccw.core/ccw.preferences.editor_color.FUNCTION=167,236,33
/instance/ccw.core/ccw.preferences.editor_color.FUNCTION.bold=false
...

/instance/com.adobe.flexide.as.core/asASDocItalic=true
/instance/com.adobe.flexide.as.core/asASDocColor=#626262
...

/instance/com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms/logcat.msg.color.assert=205,22,137
/instance/com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms/logcat.msg.color.debug=123,182,234
...

/instance/com.powerflasher.fdt.ui/AS_CONSTANTS_color=152,118,170
/instance/com.powerflasher.fdt.ui/AS_CORE_color=18,144,195
```

the lines starting with `/instance/ccw.core` will go into file `ccw.core.prefs`. Lines  `instance/com.adobe.flexide.as.core` will go into `com.adobe.flexide.as.core.prefs` and so on. You need to delete those files only. There are quite a lot of them though (i had to delete 53), easy way to sift them is to find the first one and sort by modification time they will group together.

BTW there is nice dark theme available by default in eclipse 4.7 (2017). You can try and switch color themes without this kind of hassle by installing Eclipse Color Themes plugin, it also has good selection of dark color themes too.

Answer (score 1):

you need to do the process for all individual languages you work on...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just delete your .metadata folder in your workspace and start eclipse....:)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve a similar problem like this:

1. Close the Eclipse IDE
2. Remove the .metadata folder from your eclipse workspace
3. Relaunch eclipse

The only disadvantage is that you have to re-import all your projects.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert on this, but I'll share my example with you. One guy suggested to create new eclipse preferences file or epf file using another clean install of eclipse. I made a file called clean.epf and compared it with RainbowDrops.epf (the one which messed up my highlighting and such). I noticed a huge difference between the two epf files. So, you might not want to use this method.

The whole windows --- preferences thing did not help. So, I just closed eclipse. Went to

```
My workspace directory/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/
```

and deleted the file `org.eclipse.ui.editors.prefs` and opened eclipse. It works. 
BTW, keep a back up of your .settings folders just in case.

In case you want to see some difference between rainbow and clean epf -

Rainbow -

```
file_export_version=3.0
/instance/ccw.core/ccw.preferences.editor_color.FUNCTION=167,236,33
/instance/ccw.core/ccw.preferences.editor_color.FUNCTION.bold=false
/instance/ccw.core/ccw.preferences.editor_color.FUNCTION.enabled=true
/instance/ccw.core/ccw.preferences.editor_color.FUNCTION.italic=false
/instance/ccw.core/ccw.preferences.editor_color.GLOBAL_VAR=141,218,248
...more here
```

Clean (exporting all) -

```
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/tabWidthPropagated=true
/instance/org.eclipse.mylyn.monitor.ui/org.eclipse.mylyn.monitor.activity.tracking.enabled.checked=true
/instance/org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui/org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui.filters.nonmatching.encouraged=true
@org.eclipse.mylyn.monitor.ui=3.13.0.v20140702-2155
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/useQuickDiffPrefPage=true
...more here
```

Clean (exporting only java) -

```
file_export_version=3.0
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/org.eclipse.jdt.ui.formatterprofiles.version=12
@org.eclipse.jdt.ui=3.10.100.v20140905-1343
\!/=
...end of file
```

So, I am not sure if this is the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem in Eclipse Luna (4.4.2)

1. Exit Eclipse
2. Deleted the following under the .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings directory

   - com.aptana.theme.prefs
   - com.github.eclipsecolortheme.prefs
   - org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme.prefs
3. Started Eclipse
4. In Preferences > General > Appeareance > Color Theme > check "Set all background colors to default"

Without step 4. a vertical strip near line numbers remained the older background color

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers above worked for me for Mars, so I took drastic measures.

- Possibly optional: Donwload newest version of Eclipse from their website
- Possibly optional: Find where your executable of current Eclipse's at, and remove the whole folder (you can't uninstall Eclipse through Configurations because it never really installs itself on the system)
- **Remove the .metadata folder inside your workspace folder**, e.g. `C:/Users/bram/Documents/workspace/.metadata` (you can leave the projects as they were)
- **Remove the .eclipse folder inside {User}**, e.g. `C:/Users/bram/.eclipse`
- Optional: clean file system (and registry?) with a tool such as CCleaner

The last step is definitely optional, but I'm not sure about the first two. In other words, I can't confirm that the corrupted files were inside eclipse's executable folder, inside `.eclipse` or inside the workspace's `.metadata`. I'm pretty sure `.metadata` isn't the culprit since I'd already removed that before so **my guess is that the folder** `.eclipse` **in {User} is the cause!**

If you've tried my steps, please comment whether or not they helped you and which removed folder you think solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove .metadata from your eclipse workspace 
You can find it C:\Users\username\workspace

Answer (score 0):

Not even a single answer of the above let me able to get the original theme as I expected. I tried myself & got my default theme by changing the workspace. This led me to the original theme (same-to-same) that I used to saw when installing eclipse !

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, I imported a color theme and didn't like it. I never thought reverting will be so much trouble. I installed a color theme plugin "Eclipse Color Theme 0.14.0."

I went to Windows-->preferences-->General-->Appearance-->Color Theme. I selected the Default option. It reverted to default.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try switching between different Themes option available in *General*->*Appearance*->*Colors and Fonts*.

I earlier used Dark theme in Juno. Then reverted to **Windows 7 classic** theme but was left with Black background. And that led me to this question. Having not found any solution I finally tried with **Windows XP Olive** and to my amazement black background was restored to default.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar situation for Network Preferences. Launching eclipse.exe with the clean option helped in my case

Answer (score 0):

To switch back to eclipse's original theme go to **window > preferences > General(click on drop down) > Appearance(do not click on drop down) > Themes: Light (in drop down menu) > Apply and close**. 
Now restart eclipse.

It helped me to get back the original eclipse theme.

Answer (score 0):

Open any java class -> Right clic -> Checkstyle -> Clear Checkstyle vilolations.
It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

go to windows>preferences>Java>Editor>Syntax Coloring go all the way down and click on Restore Defaults & Apply and Close

Comment: I see no new content in this answer that @RikusKhan didn't already provide in the top-voted answer.

Answer (score 0):

- Window > Preferences > Editors > **Restore Defaults**
- Window > Preferences > **Java** > Editor > Syntax Coloring > **Restore Defaults**
- Window > Preferences > **JavaScript** > Editor > Syntax Coloring > **Restore Defaults**
- Window > Preferences > Web > **CSS Files** > Editor > Syntax Coloring > **Restore Defaults**
- Window > Preferences > Web > **HTML Files** > Editor > Syntax Coloring > **Restore Defaults**
- Window > Preferences > Web > **JSP Files** > Editor > Syntax Coloring > **Restore Defaults**
- Window > Preferences > **XML** > **DTD** Files > Syntax Coloring > **Restore Defaults**
- Window > Preferences > **XML** > **XML** Files > Editor > Syntax Coloring > **Restore Defaults**
- Window > Preferences > **XML** > **XSL** > Syntax Coloring > **Restore Defaults**
- Window > Preferences > Data Management > SQL Development > SQL Editor > Syntax Coloring > **Restore Defaults**